# How to retrieve a list of ALL completed documents in docu-sign using api

Tags: docusignapi

I am writing a Java program that will download docusign documents and save to my local file system. That is already working, but now I'd like to (as a docusign admin) download ALL completed documents regardless of the envelope and document type/ID. How can I achieve this?
Right now, I am only able to retrieve ALL documents by envelope ID and document ID.

Answer (score 0):

Documents are children of envelopes.  So you need to list the envelopes, then retrieve their associated documents.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get a list of envelopes? What method do I use? Remember...I'm an admin, so I need to retrieve ALL envelopes pertaining to my account.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the list of envelopes, then get every documents are into each envelope :

Check this [***link***](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Folders/Folders/search/) in docusign support. Remember you have a [***limit***](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Retrieve-how-many-envelopes-can-be-retrieved-in-one-hour) of 5000 api calls in one hour.